# Problems in making a random seat arrangement plan app

Tags: javascript, json

So tried making a random seat arrangement project for school. With a maximum of 40 students. I used JSON for making a list of names of students and their sections.

```js
      data = '[{"firstName": "Roscon","lastName": "Advincula","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Karl","lastName": "Andrade","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Enrico","lastName": "Antoni","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Mark","lastName": "Borja","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Neru","lastName": "Capate","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Renz","lastName": "Estorba","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Jude","lastName": "Gratol","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Russel","lastName": "Lagutan","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Remy","lastName": "Lavilla","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Geofrey","lastName": "Lesigues","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Andrew","lastName": "Lorenzo","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Anilov","lastName": "Makabenta","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Justin","lastName": "Mataro","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Paul","lastName": "Naval","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Klyde","lastName": "Nical","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Luis","lastName": "Quitalig","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Alex","lastName": "Roa","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Aaron","lastName": "Salazar","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Lance","lastName": "Villegas","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Felicity","lastName": "Balasanos","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Phoebe","lastName": "Cesar","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Nikki","lastName": "Enrique","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Raycel","lastName": "Gaviola","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Lara","lastName": "Geonzon","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Seana","lastName": "Hembra","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Cristine","lastName": "Jomadiao","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Aurianne","lastName": "Lao","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Allyssa","lastName": "Larayos","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Kajia","lastName": "Malibago","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Cydie","lastName": "Manocsoc","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Princess","lastName": "Molina","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Cyril","lastName": "Monge","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Ylaine","lastName": "Nicolas","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Princess","lastName": "Obeso","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Robella","lastName": "Penachos","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Nijelu","lastName": "Ripalda","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Judy","lastName": "Salazar","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Jarelle","lastName": "Sano","section": "NOBEL"},{"firstName": "Noree","lastName": "Cayas","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Rachel","lastName": "Malate","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Joanna","lastName": "Distrajo","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Petals","lastName": "Felices","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Treshia","lastName": "Navidad","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Karen","lastName": "Albesa","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Chelsea","lastName": "Colantro","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Aimee","lastName": "Yero","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Jaeka","lastName": "Dico","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Allyssa","lastName": "De Guzman","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Gerard","lastName": "Selga","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Fiona","lastName": "Lauzon","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Jeremiah","lastName": "Calope","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Isabella","lastName": "Catindoy","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Fionna","lastName": "Lesigues","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Karyll","lastName": "Mercado","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Aliyah","lastName": "Canono","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Von","lastName": "Mendoza","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "John","lastName": "Keith","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Andrei","lastName": "Abegonia","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Jabin","lastName": "Jorvina","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Phoebe","lastName": "Lluz","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Rafael","lastName": "Garcia","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Zchryzller","lastName": "Reli","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Reoven","lastName": "Collagra","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Jais","lastName": "Ty","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Jessamine","lastName": "Catalo","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Trisha","lastName": "Bulic","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Gwyneth","lastName": "Ramos","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Xyryz","lastName": "Patagnan","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Joyce","lastName": "Malate","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Jairus","lastName": "Gariando","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Ernest","lastName": "Romero","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Dale","lastName": "Alarioa","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Kaye","lastName": "Delda","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Blessy","lastName": "Gabornes","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Karla","lastName": "Bioco","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Pearl","lastName": "Gascon","section": "PASTEUR"},{"firstName": "Charmaine","lastName": "Tan","section": "PASTEUR"}]'; 
      var data = JSON.parse(data);
      function resetMe(){
        for(y = 0; y < 40;y++){

document.getElementById("seat" + (y + 1)).innerHTML = " ";
}
      }
      function yes() {
        var sec = document.getElementById("sec").value.toUpperCase();
        var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40"];
   shuffle(myArray);
        for(y = 0; y < 40;y++){

          document.getElementById("seat" + (y + 1)).innerHTML = " ";
        }
        

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(sec == data[i].section){
                document.getElementById("seat" + myArray[i]).innerHTML = data[i].firstName + " " + data[i].lastName ;
            }
            
        }
      }
      function shuffle(a) {
        var j, x, i;
        for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          x = a[i];
          a[i] = a[j];
          a[j] = x;
        }

      }
```

```css
      body {
     background-color: peachpuff;
        font-family: "Courier New";
  font-size: X-small;
        color: inherit;
        padding: 10vh 0 0 0;
        margin: 0px;
      }
   h1{
      font-family: "Courier New";
      font-weight: normal;
      background-color: papayawhip;
      }

      #container {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        padding: 2em;
      }

      .row {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .column {
        width: 49.5%;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .column a {
        width: 15%;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 0;
        background: aliceblue;
        margin: 7px 0;
        cursor: crosshair;
      }
      .column a p {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        transition: ease 0.35s;
        opacity: 1;
      }
   table{
      font-family: "Courier New";
      font-weight: normal;
      background-color: #efefbb;
      }
```

```html
  <h1 align="center">SEAT PLAN</h1>
  <table align="center" border="1px">
    <tr><td>TEACHER'S DESK</td></tr>
</table>

<br/>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="column c1">
          <a
            ><p>Seat 1</p>
            <span id="seat1" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 2</p>
            <span id="seat2" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 3</p>
            <span id="seat3" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 4</p>
            <span id="seat4" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 5</p>
            <span id="seat5" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="column c2">
          <a
            ><p>Seat 6</p>
            <span id="seat6" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 7</p>
            <span id="seat7" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 8</p>
            <span id="seat8" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 9</p>
            <span id="seat9" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 10</p>
            <span id="seat10" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="column c1">
          <a
            ><p>Seat 11</p>
            <span id="seat11" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 12</p>
            <span id="seat12" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 13</p>
            <span id="seat13" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 14</p>
            <span id="seat14" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 15</p>
            <span id="seat15" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="column c2">
          <a
            ><p>Seat 16</p>
            <span id="seat16" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 17</p>
            <span id="seat17" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 18</p>
            <span id="seat18" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 19</p>
            <span id="seat19" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 20</p>
            <span id="seat20" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="column c2">
          <a
            ><p>Seat 21</p>
            <span id="seat21" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 22</p>
            <span id="seat22" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 23</p>
            <span id="seat23" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 24</p>
            <span id="seat24" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 25</p>
            <span id="seat25" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="column c2">
          <a
            ><p>Seat 26</p>
            <span id="seat26" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 27</p>
            <span id="seat27" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 28</p>
            <span id="seat28" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 29</p>
            <span id="seat29" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 30</p>
            <span id="seat30" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="column c2">
          <a
            ><p>Seat 31</p>
            <span id="seat31" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 32</p>
            <span id="seat32" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 33</p>
            <span id="seat33" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 34</p>
            <span id="seat34" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 35</p>
            <span id="seat35" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="column c2">
          <a
            ><p>Seat 36</p>
            <span id="seat36" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 37</p>
            <span id="seat37" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 38</p>
            <span id="seat38" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 39</p>
            <span id="seat39" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
          <a
            ><p>Seat 40</p>
            <span id="seat40" class="s-name"></span id="seat"></a
          >
        </div>
        <input id="sec" type="text" placeholder="section">
        <button onclick="yes()">Assign Random Seat Arrangement</button><button onclick="resetMe()">Reset Arrangement</button>
      </div>
```

**My problem lies in this part**

```
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(sec == data[i].section){
                document.getElementById("seat" + myArray[i]).innerHTML = data[i].firstName + " " + data[i].lastName ;
            }

        }
```

When *i* exceeds the value *40*, it will not be able to function properly as there are only 40 seats and the id tag of each seat corresponds to the seat number such as

Seat 1

.
So when I search **Nobel** It works fine but when I search **Pasteur** only 2 names pop-up, 39 names are supposed to pop-up.

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

nvm found the solution

```
 var data = JSON.parse(data);
      function resetMe(){

        for(y = 0; y < 40;y++){

document.getElementById("seat" + (y + 1)).innerHTML = " ";
}
      }
      function yes() {
        var sec = document.getElementById("sec").value.toUpperCase();
        var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40"];
   shuffle(myArray);
   var counter = 0;
        for(y = 0; y < 40;y++){

          document.getElementById("seat" + (y + 1)).innerHTML = " ";
        }


        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(sec == data[i].section){

                document.getElementById("seat" + myArray[counter]).innerHTML = data[i].firstName + " " + data[i].lastName ;
                counter++
            }

        }
        counter = 0;
      }
      function shuffle(a) {
        var j, x, i;
        for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          x = a[i];
          a[i] = a[j];
          a[j] = x;
        }

      }
```